# Migrations after switching from EDMX to Code First throws MetadataException

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations, edmx

I'm changing a project from using an EDMX file to Code First. The project is one of a few projects in a solution, and it only contains the entities and the DbContext class.

This is what I've done so far:

1. Removed the old project from the solution (but not deleted it just yet, just renamed the folder).
2. Added a new class library project to the solution, and given it the same name as the old one.
3. Used NuGet to add Entity Framework to the new project.
4. Copied all the entity classes that were generated by the old EDMX file to the new project and included them all.
5. Copied the DbContext class as well.
6. Modified the app.config file to change the connection string to a standard connection string without the metadata stuff.
7. Added a reference to all the other projects that uses to use the old project.

Everything looks good and it compiles with no errors, but when I try to `enable-migrations` it throws this error:

```
PM> enable-migrations
Checking if the context targets an existing database...
System.Data.Entity.Core.MetadataException: Unable to load the specified metadata resource.
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataArtifactLoaderCompositeResource.LoadResources(String assemblyName, String resourceName, ICollection`1 uriRegistry, MetadataArtifactAssemblyResolver resolver)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataArtifactLoaderCompositeResource.CreateResourceLoader(String path, ExtensionCheck extensionCheck, String validExtension, ICollection`1 uriRegistry, MetadataArtifactAssemblyResolver resolver)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataArtifactLoader.Create(String path, ExtensionCheck extensionCheck, String validExtension, ICollection`1 uriRegistry, MetadataArtifactAssemblyResolver resolver)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataCache.SplitPaths(String paths)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Utils.Memoizer`2.<>c__DisplayClass2.<Evaluate>b__0()
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Utils.Memoizer`2.Result.GetValue()
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Utils.Memoizer`2.Evaluate(TArg arg)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataCache.GetArtifactLoader(DbConnectionOptions effectiveConnectionOptions)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.MetadataCache.GetMetadataWorkspace(DbConnectionOptions effectiveConnectionOptions)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.GetMetadataWorkspace()
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.RetrieveMetadataWorkspaceFromConnection()
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext..ctor(EntityConnection connection, Boolean isConnectionConstructor, ObjectQueryExecutionPlanFactory objectQueryExecutionPlanFactory, Translator translator, ColumnMapFactory columnMapFactory)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalConnection.CreateObjectContextFromConnectionModel()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.CreateObjectContextFromConnectionModel()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.get_ModelBeingInitialized()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.EdmxWriter.WriteEdmx(DbContext context, XmlWriter writer)
   at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbContextExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass1.<GetModel>b__0(XmlWriter w)
   at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbContextExtensions.GetModel(Action`1 writeXml)
   at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbContextExtensions.GetModel(DbContext context)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator..ctor(DbMigrationsConfiguration configuration, DbContext usersContext, DatabaseExistenceState existenceState, Boolean calledByCreateDatabase)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator..ctor(DbMigrationsConfiguration configuration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.MigrationScaffolder..ctor(DbMigrationsConfiguration migrationsConfiguration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.ScaffoldRunner.Run()
   at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
   at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Run(BaseRunner runner)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.ScaffoldInitialCreate(String language, String rootNamespace)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.EnableMigrationsCommand.<>c__DisplayClass2.<.ctor>b__0()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action command)
Unable to load the specified metadata resource.
```

It looks like it still thinks I'm using an EDMX. I also get this error when I try to run the application.

What am I missing?

Comment: Please, try doing it in a separate solution, so that the config files are clean.  Then tell if you get any other problem.

Comment: You have to change the connection string of the starter project (asp.net or winforms project). Have you tried to change the connection string of the starter project?

Comment: @FabioLuz: Yes, that was the problem! thanks. If you add this as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change the connection string of the starter project (asp.net or winforms project).